# jQuery post not everytime woking firefox

Tags: jquery, html, firefox, post

I have a HTML form:

```
<form method="post" id="input_form" onSubmit="return save_mail();">
    <input type="text" value="enter your email" id="mail" name="mail"/>
    <button type="submit" id="save_btn" >Sign up</button>  
    <div id="warning"></div>
</form>
```

The javascript code looks like this:

```
function validateEmail(email) {
    var re = /\S+@\S+\.\S+/;
    return re.test(email);
}

function wrongEmail() {
    document.getElementById("warning").innerHTML="wrong email format";
}

function rightEmail() {
    document.getElementById("warning").innerHTML="";
}

function save_mail() {
    var pom=document.getElementById("mail").value;
    if (validateEmail(pom)) {
        $.post("php/sign_up.php", {mail : pom});
        rightEmail();
        alert("heey"); // if I remove this alert, it doesn't work on FF anymore
        return true;
    }
    else {
        wrongEmail();
        return false;
    }
}
```

It all works fine on Chrome and also Firefox, but if I remove the alert from my JS code, it doesn't work anymore. I don't know, how is this possible. There are no errors according to FF or Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

`$.post` is asynchronous by default so all the code after the post will execute straight after the ajax request is made not after it is finished as I think you are probably expecting.

In order to have code execute after the ajax request is complete make use of the deferred functions or the success callback for `$.ajax`

```
$.post("php/sign_up.php",{mail: pom}, function(){
    //this is where you execute code once the sign_up.php script has been called
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Add you actions inside success of jQuery Post,The jQuery recommended style is

```
var jqxhr = $.post( "example.php", function() {
   alert( "success" );
})
.done(function() {
    alert( "second success" );
})
.fail(function() {
    alert( "error" );
})
.always(function() {
    alert( "finished" );
 });
```